# Nginx error_log levels difference

Tags: linux, nginx, logging

There are `warn, error, crit, alert` and `emerg` levels.

But I can't find from the documentation what each means... especially I'm interested in the difference between crit, alert and emerg levels.

Can anyone lead me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

These are syslog(3) log levels. It's up to the developers which level they use for any particular event, but the [syslog(3) manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) gives rough guidance. From the user's perspective, it really depends on how much volume is considered useful in the log files.